# autotest-growl not reporting any failures or errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autotest, growl

I have autotest set up and it's running fine and reporting errors correctly, but the growl notification always ignores any failures and errors, which makes it completely useless..

```
autotest -f
...
==============================================================================
pass: 2,  fail: 0,  error: 1
total: 3 tests with 173 assertions in 17.747792 seconds
==============================================================================
```

But the growl notifications never report any errors:

```
TRUNK: All unit tests passed.
173 assertions in 3 tests
```

Here are my gems:

```
autotest-fsevent (0.2.8)
autotest-growl (0.2.16)
autotest-rails (4.1.2)
growl_notify (0.0.3)
redgreen (1.2.2)
ZenTest (4.9.0)
```

.autotest

```
require "autotest/fsevent"
require "autotest/growl"
require "redgreen/autotest"
...
```

Other stuff

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
Rails 2.3.14
OS X 10.8.2
Growl 2.0.1
```

Help!

Comment: So what's the problem? I thought something never reporting errors was good :P

Comment: I agree with Charles. Maybe the code is fine and your tests are passing.

Comment: The tests are failing but the notification says everything passed.

Comment: There's one error from the console log but not reported in growl. Same behavior with failures. I updated the problem to clarify this.